# What it the best way to send log info (callstack for example) from a DCOM server to client in an exception cenario

Tags: delphi, com, dcom

I want to send detailed info about exceptions from a DCOM server to client. Today we already have a log in server, but it would make our lives simpler having both callstacks (client and server) in the same log in client. 
We achivied to do this by making a second call to server after the exception, to get the log, but it would be better to not have this second call, and send togheter with the error. 
The error arrive in client with an object of `TExcepInfo` (tagEXCEPINFO). This struct does not have any specific field of a "detailed log", or additional info. It does have an `bstrSource` field that I could use, I think.

My question is: is there a "best practice" to do this, or some specific field meant for it, or could I just use this `bstrSource`? Or maybe send in the `bstrDescription`, that is where the exception message goes, and split this in client, something like that?

PS.: Delphi 5. We have a migration to Delphi Tokyo, but the solution have to be for both of then.

Comment: I think I'll keep calling server to get the detailed log. Apparently the `bstrSource` field is just a description to where the error occured, so would be weird to use it for this porpouse. If anyone has another solution, I'll be happy to know

Comment: I'd suggest trying to use that Source or Description field indeed. Not much else you can do. If neither work, I don't see any solution except making the separate call. 
Or you could just log them separately and merge the logs later if you have to, but that can be tricky with timing issues. A log service like Splunk can be helpful. Also it's great if you can pass some request id for each call that both the client and the server use for logging. That makes it way easier to correlate the logs of both sides.